# good explanation of __read_mostly, __init, __exit macros

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel

The macro expansion of `__read_mostly` :

```
#define __read_mostly __attribute__((__section__(".data..read_mostly"))
```

This one is from `cache.h`

`__init`:

```
#define __init          __section(.init.text) __cold notrace
```

from `init.h`

`__exit`:

```
#define __exit          __section(.exit.text) __exitused __cold notrace
```

After searching through net i have not found any good explanation of
what is happening there.

Additonal question : I have heard about various "linker magic"
employed in kernel development. Any information
regarding this will be wonderful.

I have some ideas about these macros about **what they do**. Like `__init` supposed to indicate that the function code can be removed after initialization. `__read_mostly` is for indicating that the data is seldom written and by this it minimizes cache misses. But i have not idea about **How they do it**. I mean they are `gcc` extensions. So in theory they can be demonstrated by small userland c code.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried to test the `__section__` with arbitrary section name. the test code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __read_mostly __attribute__((__section__("MY_DATA")))

struct ro {
    char a;
    int b;
    char * c;
};

struct ro my_ro  __read_mostly = {
    .a = 'a',
    .b = 3,
    .c = NULL,
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("hello");
    printf("my ro %c %d %p \n", my_ro.a, my_ro.b, my_ro.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Now with `__read_mostly` the generated assembly code :

```
    .file   "ro.c"
.globl my_ro
    .section    MY_DATA,"aw",@progbits
    .align 16
    .type   my_ro, @object
    .size   my_ro, 16
my_ro:
    .byte   97
    .zero   3
    .long   3
    .quad   0
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "hello"
.LC1:
    .string "my ro %c %d %p \n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $24, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    call    printf
    movq    my_ro+8(%rip), %rcx
    movl    my_ro+4(%rip), %edx
    movzbl  my_ro(%rip), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %ebx
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    movl    %ebx, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $24, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Now without the `__read_mostly` macro the assembly code remains more or less the same.

this is the diff

```
--- rm.S    2012-07-17 16:17:05.795771270 +0600
+++ rw.S    2012-07-17 16:19:08.633895693 +0600
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
    .file   "ro.c"
 .globl my_ro
-   .section    MY_DATA,"aw",@progbits
+   .data
    .align 16
    .type   my_ro, @object
    .size   my_ro, 16
```

So essentially only the a subsection is created, nothing fancy.

Even the objdump disassmbly does not show any difference.

So my final conclusion about them, its the **linker's job** do something for data section marked with a special name. I think linux kernel uses some kind of custom **linker script** do achieve these things.

One of the thing about `__read_mostly`, data which were put there can be grouped and managed in a way so that cache misses can be reduced.

Someone at **lkml** submitted a patch to remove `__read_mostly`. Which spawned a fascinated discussion on the merits and demerits of `__read_mostly`.

here is the link : https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/12/13/477

I will post further update on `__init` and `__exit`.

**UPDATE 2**

These macros `__init` , `__exit` and `__read_mostly` put the contents of **data**(in case of `__read_mostly`) and **text**(in cases of `__init` and `__exit`) are put into custom named sections. These sections are utilized by the linker. Now as linker is not used as its default behaviour for various reasons, A **linker script** is employed to achieve the purposes of these macros.

A background may be found how a custom linker script can be used to eliminate **dead code**(code which is linked to by linker but never executed). This issue is of very high importance in embedded scenarios. This document discusses how a linker script can be fine tuned to remove **dead code** : elinux.org/images/2/2d/ELC2010-gc-sections_Denys_Vlasenko.pdf

In case kernel the initial linker script can be found `include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h`. This is not the final script. This is kind of **starting point**, the **linker script** is further modified for different platforms.

A quick look at this file the portions of interest can immediately found:

```
#define READ_MOSTLY_DATA(align)                     \
    . = ALIGN(align);                       \
    *(.data..read_mostly)                       \
    . = ALIGN(align);
```

It seems this section is using the ".data..readmostly" section.

Also you can find `__init` and `__exit` section related linker commands :

```
#define INIT_TEXT                           \
    *(.init.text)                           \
    DEV_DISCARD(init.text)                      \
    CPU_DISCARD(init.text)                      \
    MEM_DISCARD(init.text)

#define EXIT_TEXT                           \
    *(.exit.text)                           \
    DEV_DISCARD(exit.text)                      \
    CPU_DISCARD(exit.text)                      \
    MEM_DISCARD(exit.text)
```

Linking seems pretty complex thing to do :)

Comment: any explanation from the guy who down-voted me would be nice. I can learn from my mistakes and apply this knowledge in my future questions.

Comment: You are right: as far as `.init*` sections in the kernel modules are concerned, the module loader frees the memory they occupy after the module has completed its initialization. The loader also removes the entries for the symbols in these sections from the symbol table at that stage.

Comment: (continued) When processing a kernel module, the loader checks the names of the sections to determine how to process them. See, for example the code of [load_module()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c?v=3.4#L2865), etc., in the kernel sources.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[GCC attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html) are a general mechanism to give instructions to the compiler that are outside the specification of the language itself.

The common facility that the macros you list is the use of the [`__section__` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bsection_007d-function-attribute-2579) which is described as:

> The `section` attribute specifies that a function lives in a particular section. For example, the declaration:
>
> ```
> extern void foobar (void) __attribute__ ((section ("bar")));
> ```
>
> puts the function foobar in the bar section.

So what does it mean to put something in a section? An object file is divided into sections: `.text` for executable machine code, `.data` for read-write data, `.rodata` for read-only data, `.bss` for data initialised to zero, etc.  The names and purposes of these sections is a matter of platform convention, and some special sections can only be accessed from C using the `__attribute__ ((section))` syntax.

In your example you can guess that `.data..read_mostly` is a subsection of `.data` for data that will be mostly read; `.init.text` is a text (machine code) section that will be run when the program is initialised, etc.

On Linux, deciding what to do with the various sections is the job of the kernel; when userspace requests to `exec` a program, it will read the program image section-by-section and process them appropriately: `.data` sections get mapped as read-write pages, `.rodata` as read-only, `.text` as execute-only, etc.  Presumably `.init.text` will be executed before the program starts; that could either be done by the kernel or by userspace code placed at the program's entry point (I'm guessing the latter).

If you want to see the effect of these attributes, a good test is to run gcc with the `-S` option to output assembler code, which will contain the section directives.  You could then run the assembler with and without the section directives and use `objdump` or even hex dump the resulting object file to see how it differs.

Comment: I'm going to do some experimentation with the attributes listed here and will post subsequent update.  +1 for this nice organized answer.

Answer (score 18):

As far as I know, these macros are used *exclusively* by the kernel.  In theory, they could apply to *user-space*, but I don't believe this is the case.  They all *group* similar variable and code together for different effects.

### init/exit

A lot of code is needed to setup the *kernel*; this happens before any *user space* is running at all.  Ie, before the *init task* runs.  In many cases, this code is never used again.  So it would be a waste to consume *un-swappable* RAM after boot.  The familiar kernel message **Freeing init memory** is a result of the `init` section.  Some drivers maybe configured as *modules*.  In these cases, they *exit*.  However, if they are compiled into the kernel, the don't necessarily *exit* (they may *shutdown*).  This is another section to group this type of code/data.

### cold/hot

Each **cache** line has a fixed sized.   You can maximize a **cache** by putting the same type of data/function in it.  The idea is that often used code can go side by side.  If the **cache** is four instructions, the end of one *hot* routine should merge with the beginning of the next *hot* routine.  Similarly, it is good to keep seldom used code together, as we hope it never goes in the **cache**.

### read_mostly

The idea here is similar to **hot**; the difference with data we can update the values.  When this is done, the entire cache line becomes *dirty* and must be *re-written* to main RAM.  This is needed for multi-CPU consistency and when that **cache line** goes stale.  If nothing has changed in the difference between the CPU **cache** version and main memory, then nothing needs to happen on an *eviction*.  This optimizes the RAM bus so that other important things can happen.

These items are strictly for the kernel.  Similar tricks could (are?) be implemented for *user space*.  That would depend on the *loader* in use; which is often different depending on the *libc* in use.

Comment: Some of these ideas can/are applied to user space.  For instance, function maybe in separate files, yet call each other.  With *LTO* (load time optimization), the function maybe placed beside each other.  With user space you have L1/L2 cache, but also paging of text which takes place in 4k chunks.  People have used this idea to optimize loading of Qt applications.  Linux is lazy in loading code and will fetch from (NAND) disk as the code executes.  Grouping early Qt init code together will minimize the 4k page loads.  Hot and cold are attributes supported for userspace (`.text.hot`...)

Comment: LTO is link-time, not "load-time" https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html

Comment: @poige The semantics of what I am saying are correct.  I mis-typed 'Load' instead of 'Link'.  At link time, the compiler may chose to inline or place functions in separate modules ('C files' or whatever this 10+ year question is about) co-located in the output binary.  Thanks for correcting me pedantically.