# netdev_err() implementation in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I was troubleshooting a network driver and most of the error messages were output using netdev_err(). When searche, I could not find the definition of netdev_err() in kernel source. Instead, I came upon the following .
__printf(2, 3) __cold
void netdev_err(const struct net_device *dev, const char *format, ...);

1. what's the meaning of above declaration?
2. Where an I find definition of netdev_err()

Looked the whole kernel source. Couuld not find the definition of a routine.

Comment: "what's the meaning of above declaration?" - What is **exactly** not clear with the function's declaration? ` Do you know what `__cold` specifier means (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19233388/3440745)? Do you know what `__printf` means (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825588/what-does-this-generic-function-do)?

Comment: As for the function definition, it is provided in [net/core/dev.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/dev.c#L11277), via the macro which is parametrized by the printk-level parameter.